# Add density to linestring

Tags: geojson, turfjs

Is there a turfjs method that will let me increase the density of a linestring?  If not, is there some other one-line to do that?

```
var line = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        -24.78515625,
        2.7235830833483856
      ],
      [
        -6.328125,
        0.3515602939922709
      ]
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "increase the density", but I'll assume you mean you want to add more point coordinates to the linestring. I don't know of any built-in way of doing that, but it wouldn't be too hard to do it yourself if you just need to add more point coordinates into the linestring.

One way of doing this would be to get the midpoint of the first two points and add its coordinates to the linestrings coordinates. There is a turf function for this called `turf.midpoint()`. Here is a link to the documentation for that.

http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-midpoint/

You should be able to create two points using the existing coordinates for the linestring. You would then call turf midpoint on those two points to obtain a new point in the middle of them. You can then take the coordinates from the resulting point and add it to the linestring. Note that you will want to insert the coordinates in between the two existing coordinates, not just push it onto the end.

If that is not what you meant, or if you need a code example just say so and I will update this answer.